# Run a command before checking out files from GIT in TFS Build

Tags: .net, git, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

As part of my TFS Build I'm installing some Windows Services from the latest build on checked out source code from GIT.

My issue comes when TFS needs to checkout files again and some of the solution files are still in use (because the whole Windows services are running) and the whole build **fails** (because there're files in use and it can't clean the build directory).

I didn't find a way to execute some command or script as a step before the files are being checked out.

Note I'm using the new web/scriptable build system that was introduced on TFS 2015.

Comment: Why do you want to check out files during build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't execute commands or script as a step before Get Sources(check out). The first step in vNext build is "Get sources" and it's a default step. After "Get sources", the tasks can be run.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I was needing this because I was installing a Windows service (Topshelf) at the end of the build, and the whole Windows service was installed from the built sources in the same location where the whole sources were checked out. That is, when the 2nd build was going to be done, some executables and satellite assemblies were locked because they were in use.

Comment: This is the reason behind needing to execute some command before the "Get source" built-in step.

Comment: Finally, my solution was using a Powershell command step to copy these Windows services' binaries to other location during the whole build and I also started these Windows services as the last build step. Since these are now executed from other location, I don't need to stop them as the first step but it can be done just before copying the fresh binaries and starting them again